# General form of a connection with zero curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for proofs of the following two theorems:

**Theorem 1.** On a connected and simply-connected open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^3$, functions $L^p_{ij}\in C^1(\Omega)$ are given that satisfy
$$
R^i_{jkl}\equiv\partial_k L^i_{jl}-\partial_l L^i_{jk}+L^h_{jl} L^i_{hk}-L^h_{jk} L^i_{hl}=0\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(1)
$$
in $\Omega$. Let $[F^0_{ij}]$ be an invertible matrix. Then there exists a unique solution to the PDE:
$$ \partial_{i} F_{lj}=L^p_{ij} F_{lp},\,\,\,F_{ij}(x_0)=F^0_{ij}.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(2)$$

**Theorem 2.** The general form of a connection with coefficients $L^p_{ij}$ with zero  Riemann-Christoffel curvature is
$$L^p_{ij}=(F^{-1})^{pl}\partial_i F_{lj}.\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(3)$$

These theorems can be given the following interpretation:

*The integrability condition of the PDE $(2)$ is $(1)$ and a general solution of the PDE $(1)$ is $(3)$*.

Please note that *the connection is not torsion free*, i.e., $L^p_{ij}\ne L^p_{ji}$.

There is a proof of **Theorem 1** in the book: *An Introduction to Differential Geometry with Applications to Elasticity, P. Ciarlet*, (link: http://www6.cityu.edu.hk/rcms/publications/ln7.pdf), which appears in parts (i) and (ii) in the proof of Theorem 1.6-1 therein (page 28). But Ciarlet has used the symmetry $L^p_{ij}= L^p_{ji}$ in order to prove *uniqueness*.

It would be of much help if someone could suggest me references to find proofs of the above theorems.